# Single neuron delta rule convergence for sigmoid

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying delta rule learning with **AND** example, and i have noticed that the learning converges faster and better when i do **not** apply derivative of sigmoid activation in weight correction.

I am using **bias** neuron.

If i understand correctly, **delta rule** should consider derivative of activation function for weight adjustment: Δ Wk(n) = η∗()∗′(ℎ)∗().

where e(n) = desired_output - neuron_output.

This is sigmoid i am using to calculate output:

```
public double calc(double sum) {
    return 1 / (1 + Math.pow(Math.E, -sum));
}
```

According to page 33, step 4 in this [dela rule](http://uni-obuda.hu/users/fuller.robert/delta.pdf), weight update should be:

```
double delta = learningRate * error * estimated * (1 - estimated) * input;
```

It works better without:

```
estimated * (1 - estimated)
```

This is pretty much code for training with delta rule:

```
@Override
public void train(List<LearningSample> samples, double[] weights, Function<double[], Double> neuronOutput) {

    double[] weightDelta = new double[weights.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        // Collections.shuffle(samples);
        for (LearningSample sample : samples) {
            // sigmoid of dot product of weights and input vector, including bias
            double estimated = neuronOutput.apply(sample.getInput());
            double error = sample.getDesiredOutput() - estimated;
            // this commented out version actually works better than the one bellow
            // double delta = learningRate * error;
            double delta = learningRate * error * estimated * (1 - estimated);
            // aggregate delta per weight for each sample in epoch
            deltaUpdate(delta, weightDelta, sample.getInput());
        }

        // batch update weights at the end of training epoch
        for (int weight = 0; weight < weights.length; weight++) {
            weights[weight] += weightDelta[weight];
        }

        weightDelta = new double[weights.length];
    }      
}


private void deltaUpdate(double delta, double[] weightsDelta, double[] input) {
    for (int feature = 0; feature < input.length; feature++) {
        weightsDelta[feature] = weightsDelta[feature] + delta * input[feature];
    }
}
```

Training sample for AND looks like this:

```
List<LearningSample> samples = new ArrayList<>();
LearningSample sample1 = new LearningSample(new double[] { 0, 0 }, 0);
LearningSample sample2 = new LearningSample(new double[] { 0, 1 }, 0);
LearningSample sample3 = new LearningSample(new double[] { 1, 0 }, 0);
LearningSample sample4 = new LearningSample(new double[] { 1, 1 }, 1);
```

Bias **1** is injected as 0th component in the constructor.

Order in which output was tested after learning:

```
System.out.println(neuron.output(new double[] { 1,   1, 1 }));
System.out.println(neuron.output(new double[] { 1,   0, 0 }));
System.out.println(neuron.output(new double[] { 1,   0, 1 }));
System.out.println(neuron.output(new double[] { 1,   1, 0 }));
```

This is result when i omit derivative of sigmoid from delta calculation:

**10000 iterations**

- 0.9666565909058419
- 2.05087653022386E-5
- 0.023803593411627456
- 0.023803593411627456

**35000 iterations**

- 0.9903810162649429
- 4.6475933225663785E-7
- 0.006870001301253153
- 0.006870001301253153

These are the result with applied derivative:

**10000 iterations**

- 0.8446651307271656
- 0.004030424878725242
- 0.129178264332045
- 0.129178264332045

**35000 iterations**

- 0.9218773156128204
- 4.169603485934177E-4
- 0.06555977437019253
- 0.06555977437019253

Learning rate is: 0.021, and starting weight of bias is: -2.

The error is smaller and approximation of function much better in first example without derivative.
Why is that ?

**UPDATE**

From the answer by @Umberto, there are a couple of things i would like to verify:

- accident experiment where `delta = learningRate * error * input`, is in fact valid since this minimizes cross entropy cost function ?
  **Yes**
- cross entropy apparently works better for classification, so when should MSE be used as a cost function ?
  **Regression**

As a note i am running the output through threshold function, it's just not shown here, so this is binary classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple. You minimize different cost functions. In your case (as from the slide) you minimize the error squared. If you use a cost function (cross-entropy) in the form I describe in my derivation here [github link](https://github.com/michelucci/Logistic-Regression-Explained/blob/master/Logistic%20Regression%20from%20scratch.ipynb), you will get the update of the weights that works faster. Usually in classification problems (normally you use a sigmoid neuron for binary classification) the squared error is not really a good cost function.

If you use cross entropy, you will need to use `learningRate * error * input;` (with the right sign, according to how you define your error).

As a side note what you are actually doing is logistic regression...

Hope that helps. If you need more information let me know. Check my link, there I do a complete derivation of the mathematics behind it.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, could you please clarify a couple of things in updated question ?

Comment: To answer your questions: _accident experiment where delta = learningRate * error * input, is in fact valid since this minimizes cross entropy cost function ?_ : yes. second question: usually you use MSE for regression. Check for example this link: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-main-reasons-not-to-use-MSE-as-a-cost-function-for-Logistic-Regression